# How do you specify return type on a callable parameter with reST docstring?

Tags: python, restructuredtext, docstring

Here's a working example with type hinting where I can annotate the parameter that it takes an int and a string and returns a boolean:

```py
from typing import Callable

def func(another_func: Callable[[int, str], bool]):
    pass
```

[image: Type hinting function]

The relevant part is `-> bool` in the picture above. I'm trying to do the same thing with a reStructuredText docstring:

```py
def func2(another_func):
    """ :param function[int, str] another_func: """
```

[image: reSt example]

This is the closest I've gotten in the picture above. Writing `function[[int, str], bool]` doesn't work

- PyCharm 2021.2.4 x64
- Python 3.9

Comment: use `""" :param (int, str) -> bool another_func: """`

Comment: Nice that's it, thanks @Matiiss! You wanna turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to just like how PyCharm showed you how it looks like when using `typing.Callable`:

```py
""" :param (int, str) -> bool another_func: """
```